# Reload page to show injected jQuery UI elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am writing a jQuery Plugin to play a simple game. The game injects all necessary html into the div where it is called and links its css sheet to the head. The issue I am running into is that if I call location.reload after the injection, it refreshes the page back to before I added the HTML. If I don't call it, everything but my jQuery UI Sliders shows up. How do I reload just those sliders so they will show up after I inject them? (Everything works perfectly if I just paste the HTML into the body of the test HTML file - the only issue is when I dynamically add it when, say they push a button.)

As requested, here is some of the code I am using to do this:
// Load the HTML and CSS.
        $("head").append(
            '');
        $("body").append('');
        $("#load-button").remove();

```
    $("#game").append(
        "<!-- Generated Swatch-->\n" +
        "<div id='generatedSwatch' class ='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'></div> </br>\n" +
        "<!-- Score -->\n" +
        "<p id='score'>Score: 0</p>\n" +
        "<!-- Sliders -->\n" +
        "<div class='slider-row'>\n" +
        "    <div id='red'></div>\n" +
        "    <input type='text' id='rval' class='input-box'></input> </br>\n" +
        "</div>\n" +
        "<div class='slider-row'>\n" +
        "    <div id='green'></div>\n" +
        "    <input type='text' id='gval' class='input-box'></input> </br>\n" +
        "</div>\n" +
        "<div class='slider-row'>\n" +
        "    <div id='blue'></div>\n" +
        "    <input type='text' id='bval' class='input-box'></input> </br>\n" +
        "</div>\n" +
        "<!-- Got It Button -->\n" +
        "<button id='got-it' onclick='calculateScore()' class='button'>Got It</button>\n" +
        "<!-- Picked Swatch -->\n" +
        "<div id='pickedSwatch' class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'></div>\n" +
        "<!-- Percent Error -->\n" +
        "<p id='error'>Percent Error: </p>\n" +
        "<!-- Next Button -->\n" +
        "<button id='next' onclick='generateSwatch()' class='button'>Next</button>\n" +
        "<!-- Game Over Message -->\n" +
        "<p id='game-over'>Game Over</p>\n" +
        "<!-- Play Again -->\n" +
        "<button id='play-again' onclick='playAgain()' class='button'>Play Again</button>"
    );

    // Hide Elements.
    $("#pickedSwatch").hide();
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#next").hide();
    $("#game-over").hide();
    $("#play-again").hide();

    // Make Sliders Work
    $("#red,#green,#blue").slider(
    {
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        max: 255,
        value: 127,
        slide: refreshSwatch,
        change: refreshSwatch
    });
    $("#red").slider( "value", 255);
    $("#green").slider( "value", 140);
    $("#blue").slider("value", 60);

    // Code to move slider when box changed.
    $("#rval").change(function() 
    {
        $("#red").slider("value", $(this).val());
    });
    $("#gval").change(function() 
    {
        $("#green").slider("value", $(this).val());
    });
    $("#bval").change(function() 
    {
        $("#blue").slider("value", $(this).val());
    });

    // Generates the swatch for the first time and sets the turns.
    generateSwatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

location.reload does not need to be used MOST of the time, jQuery can update the page without a refresh. The information injected here will be lost as jQuery manipulates the DOM after it has loaded and does not maintain state unless implied.

Could you maybe post some of the code you are using at the moment?

Comment: Sorry, I was tied up before. I added an excerpt of my code so you can see.